# Database design rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Posts, Types (e.g. tutorial, article), Categories (e.g. WordPress, HTML), Tags (e.g. plugin, theme, api) in my rails app.

I need to access the following links:

```
example.com
  -> gets all post

example.com/types/tutorial
  -> gets all post under tutorial type 

example.com/categories/wordpress
  -> gets all post under wordpress category
example.com/types/tutorial/categories/wordpress
  -> gets all post under wordpress category in tutorial type 

example.com/tags/plugin
  -> gets all post under plugin tag
example.com/types/tutorial/tags/plugin
  -> gets all post under plugin tag in tutorial type
example.com/types/tutorial/categories/wordpress/tags/plugin
  -> gets all post under plugin tag in tutorial type and in wordpress category
```

**I have several questions:**

1. Is this a good way to organize the posts?
2. Isn't it better to use search query for getting all extra stuff?
3. Are the following rails codes correct or should I use joined tables or are my codes wrong?
4. Suggest a real-world example, please.

**Rails codes**

```
rails g scaffold Type
rails g scaffold Category type:refeferences
rails g scaffold Tag type:references category:refeferences
rails g scaffold Post type:references category:refeferences tag:refeferences
```

Comment: With the current design posts can only have 1 category, 1 tag and 1 type, in order to allow more than one you need a habtm join table.

Comment: A general result from your comment: if I need a post to have 1 category, I need to have the current design but if I need a post to have multiple categories, I need to create a joined table. correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
example.com
  # Shows all posts

example.com/categories
example.com/tags
example.com/types
  # Shows posts for x

example.com/categories/wordpress
example.com/types/html
example.com/tags/theme
  # Shows posts for y
```

This puts all your content in the `posts` model, allowing you to assign different `categories`, `types` and `tags` to each post, using `habtm`

I'd set it up like this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :types, :tags
end

#app/models/category.rb / tag.rb / plugin.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_may :posts
end

#config/routes.rb
root to: "posts#index"
resources :posts, :tags, :categories, :plugins


#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```